# where are the .pickle files saved?

Tags: python, macos, zipline

I'm a beginner to zipline and I have been trying to run the example here given in the QuickStart:

https://github.com/quantopian/zipline

I was able to get this command to run on my mac in terminal:

```
python run_algo.py -f dual_moving_average.py --symbols AAPL --start 2011-1-1 --end 2012-1-1 -o dma.pickle
```

But after spinning for a bit, It was done and I expected the `dma.pickle` file to be saved in the same folder as the file: `dual_moving_average.py` but it was not saved there.

I'm not sure where it is saved on my mac, the instructions don't seem to say.

I ran a spotlight search on my mac for `dma.pickle`and nothing picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the parameters for output should not be `-o`.

It should be `-output`.

So this will output the pickle:

```
python -f dual_moving_average.py --start 2011-1-1 --end 2012-1-1 -output dma.pickle
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on Windows 10. I used this command and the copied the output file manually to my Jupyter folder. Did this from the command line.

```
zipline run -f ./anaconda3/lib/site-packages/zipline/examples/buyapple.py --start 2000-1-1 --end 2000-1-2 -o c:\buyapple_out.pickle
```